# PHP Excel access style array key in applyFromArray

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I am trying to make an array which contain all design and access the array key in `applyFromArray()`:

```
$styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => '000000'),
        'size'  => 11,
        'name'  => 'Verdana'
    ),
    'alignment' => array(
        'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
    )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->applyFromArray($styleArray['font']);
```

Answer (score 1):

For your style array :

```
$styleArray = array(
        'font'  => array(
            'bold'  => true,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '000000'),
            'size'  => 11,
            'name'  => 'Verdana'
        ),
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        )
);
```

Call `getFont()` before applying the font style

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A1:D1')
            ->getFont() //Add this call to get the font object
            ->applyFromArray($styleArray['font']);
```

In case you want to use all your style array  :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A1:D1')
            ->applyFromArray($styleArray); // Remove the 'font' index
```